# Adjoint operator and isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T \in B(X,Y)$ and $T^{*} \in B(Y^{*},X^{*})$ where $Z^*$ is dual space of $Z$ and $T^{*}$ is the adjoint operator of $T$. Suppose $T(X)$ is closed in $Y$.

In this book, https://www.math.snu.ac.kr/~wylee/OperatorTheory_2010/Lecture%20Notes%20on%20OperatorTheory.pdf ,  pg. 9, the autor uses this fact:

a) $T^{-1}(0) \cong  (T^{-1}(0))^{*}$

b)  $(Y/(TX)) \cong (Y/(TX))^{*}$

where  $\cong$ must mean that there exist a linear bijective.

But I have no idea how I prove this, i.e., (a) and (b).

In this book, An Invitation to Operator Theory, by Abramovich andAliprantis, pg. 156, they assumed the fact (b).

Thank you

Comment: There must be further conditions, generally it's false.

Comment: @DanielFischer If we suppose $T$ is a fredholm operator, why is it true? Thank you

Comment: If $T$ is a Fredholm operator, then $\ker T$ and $Y/\operatorname{im} T$ are finite-dimensional. For finite-dimensional spaces you have the isomorphism with the dual.

Answer (score 0):

Take any normed space $X$. If $\dim X < \infty$ then surely $X\cong X^*$ (dual basis). If $X$ is infinite-dimensional, then so is $X^*$ (consequence of Hahn-Banach). So, again, $X\cong X^*$.

Comment: Hi, could  you tell me where I can find this consequence? Thank you

Comment: That both spaces are infinite-dimensional doesn't mean they're isomorphic, even if we're only looking at linear isomorphisms, not topological isomorphisms.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer You are right. However, we always have $\dim X = \dim X^*$, and that is what is actually needed in the proof in the above referenced book. But I think it is an interesting question whether always $X\cong X^*$ holds (only algebraically)?

Comment: Per [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684257/adjoint-operator-and-isomorphism#comment3438310_1684257), the situation is that $T$ is a Fredholm operator, so we have finite dimensions and all is fine. In general, we don't always have $\dim X = \dim X^{\ast}$. The algebraic dual of an infinite-dimensional space $E$ always has strictly larger dimension than $E$. For the topological dual of a TVS $X$, the dimension of $X^{\ast}$ can be smaller or larger than (or equal to) the dimension of $X$.

Comment: If $\kappa > 1$ is a cardinal with $\kappa^{\aleph_0} = \kappa$, then $\ell^1(\kappa)$ has dimension $\kappa$, but its dual $\ell^{\infty}(\kappa)$ has dimension $2^{\kappa} > \kappa$. I'm not sure whether the topological dual of a _normed_ space can have smaller dimension than the space itself, but for a TVS, just endow $\ell^{\infty}(\kappa)$ with the weak$^{\ast}$ topology so its topological dual will be $\ell^1(\kappa)$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Let me refer to your second but last comment. In the book, $T$ is only assumed to have closed range. It is not assumed to be Fredholm. Moreover, $X^*$ denotes the topological dual, here. So, indeed, we always have $\dim X = \dim X^*$. Here, by "$\dim$" I mean either the usual finite dimension or just $\infty$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Thanks for answering my question in such detail. :o)

Comment: If $T$ is only assumed to have closed range, the assertion is wrong. Take $T = 0 \colon \ell^1(\kappa) \to \ell^1(\kappa)$ with $\kappa$ as above. If you don't distinguish between different infinite dimensions, then equality of dimensions doesn't say anything about existence of an algebraic isomorphism between the spaces in the infinite-dimensional case. Much less about isomorphisms in the category of topological vector spaces.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the author uses the definition of dimension as in my comment above. He only is much too sloppy in using the symbol $\cong$.